# inserting count into declared variable gives 1064 error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm using this code to insert the count of the table into a variable but it gives syntax error: 1064

```
SET @findTableRows = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(id) INTO ',currentTableRows,' FROM ',aTableName);
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @findTableRows;
   EXECUTE stmt2;
```

error is >>>>

```
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 FROM z_wallet_txn_2021_02' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "CALL wallet_txn_cron('2021-02-03 11:28:48.000')"
    }
```

Comment: Yuou cannot refer to local variable in prepared statement. Use user-defined variable instead.

Comment: The source of your current error is the fact that CONCAT uses the value of your variable (which is `0`) and the query become invalid (such column name cannot be used without quoting). But if you fix this error you'd receive 'Unknown variable' error because local variables are out of context in prepared statement.

Comment: so, what's the way to insert the table count into a variable where table name is varibale

Comment: ```SET @findTableRows = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(id) INTO @currentTableRows FROM ',aTableName);``` and, after execution, get needed value with`SELECT @currentTableRows`.